# How to display the variation of a custom display in Twig

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

In my type of product variation, I have 4 different display :

- Default
- Panier (Cart)
- Teaser
- Teaser relation

[image]

I have created a template for product type and want to display the "Photo" field of the "Teaser" display of the product variation type.

Here is what I put in my template:

```
{{ product.variation_field_produit_image }}
```

The problem is that it displays the "Photo" field of the "Default" display.

How to get the "Photo" field of the "Teaser" display?

Comment: It should be taking the one from the matching view mode, "teaser" in your case. Can you check whether you're running latest Commerce (2.9)?

Comment: Did you solve this? If yes How?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another template for that specific view mode.

The naming of that template should be `commerce-product-variation--product-type--view-mode.html.twig`.

So you can create a template called `commerce-product-variation--PRODUCTTYPE--teaser.html.twig`, and then print the image field from there.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not my question. I already have this file. I want to display a precise display mode of the type of variation

Answer (score 1):

Try the [bamboo twig module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bamboo_twig) with

```
{{ bamboo_render_image_style('public://antistatique.jpg', 'thumbnail') }}
```

or

```
{{ bamboo_render_entity('node', 2, 'teaser') }}
```